# VScode Linter breaks With Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, selenium-webdriver, static-analysis

I'm trying to use Selenium on my project, but as soon as I request for the driver, all code bellow gets dark, as if they would not be executed, as seen on the picture. Is there a way I can fix that?

The code bellow runs fine, the problem is just the linter.

[image]